# How to setup area of focus mode in Nikon D90?

Tags: camera-basics, nikon-d90

I have a D90 and have tried to set it to area of focus single point, center point,normal. It is not going to this setting, when I look through the lens after setting it the area of focus is on the left. Not the center. Am I doing something wrong or does my camera have a glitch? Please respond! Thank you!

Comment: Can you post pictures that demonstrate what you mean?

Comment: Welcome Heather! Can you post a detailed step-by-step list of what you did, what behavior you expected, and what the actual behavior is?

Comment: I got confused by this initially too.  John's answer below is correct.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you've gotten into "single focus point" mode, so now you can just use the d-pad on the back to move that highlighted focus point around in the viewfinder.  The center of the d-pad returns the focus point conveniently to the center.

Comment: Also, you can hit the OK ( center pad button ) to return the focus point to the center/middle point, although, you need to do this when there is nothing on the LCD display ( same procedure as for using the d-pad to move the focus point around ). I usually half-press the shutter, then hit the OK or d-pad to move focus point.

Comment: There is also a lock just below the center pad button, if you want to keep the focus point always in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens for me when the lens gets any dirty or "oily" ( after kids touching it with a finger or so ) - then it focuses at the same point all the time :)